# Read Extended ASCII Characters from File and Convert to ASCII Decimal Value

Tags: c, type-conversion

I am trying to read the contents of a file (which contains both 'standard' text and 'binary' data).

I then need to take that character (standard or extended ASCII) and get the corresponding Decimal (int) ASCII value.

I am having a heck of time getting it to work correctly.

Here is a snippet of the code to help show what I am currently doing...

```
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r+");

char *value = NULL;

size_t charSize = sizeof(char) + 1;

value = malloc(charSize);

strcpy(value, "0");

fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);

fgets(value, charSize, fp);

int c = (int)value;

free(value);
```

I read a thing that was saying that you needed to use an unsigned char for the extended ascii, however changing to unsigned char didn't solve the problem (and gave compile warnings)

I also tried using wchar_t with the code:

```
....

wchar_t *value = NULL;
value = malloc(2);

wcscpy(value, (wchar_t *)"");

fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);

fgetws(value, 2, fp);

int c = (int)value;
```

None of these seem to work. I either get a 0 for basically everything, or some 'random' value.

For example using any of the three I get:
value: %  (correct)
c: 76678304  (number is different each time but in this same 'range')(something tells me this isn't correct) :)

So I am obviously doing something wrong but I just can't seem to figure it out...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is:

```
int c = (int)value;
```

It should be:

```
int c = *value;
```

You're dereferencing value to get the character at that position.  This is equivalent to `value[0]`.  Before, you were casting a pointer to an int, which explains the large garbage values.  Don't cast your problems away.

The `strcpy` is redundant, since `fgets` will write both bytes (the last being a NUL-terminator) unless it has an error or EOF.  If you did want to NUL-terminate it before-hand, you would use '\0' (NUL), not '0' (ASCII digit 0).  And you could simply do:

```
*value = '\0';
```

Comment: That seems to work GREAT for '%' using char. Do I need to use something else for extended ascii or can I still use char?

Comment: Actually you should instead make sure the array/string pointer type is `unsigned char *` (or cast it to such) before reading from it. BTW there is no such thing as "extended ASCII".

Comment: +1 for remarking that adding explicit casts to avoid warning/errors is usually indicative that the code is wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far more complicated than it needs to be - you can simply do this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r+");

fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);

int c = fgetc(fp);
```